# PhpStorm fails to connect to FTP while FileZilla connects

Tags: ftp, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to setup FTP connection with my newly purchased domain. Apparently, this one brings problems with connection.
`FileZilla` connects well, but PhpStorm results to a

> FTP response 421 received. Server closed connection

I have talked with my hosting service provider, they seem also to have no real clue as what could be the problem. I have also checked most solutions available online like trying with Passive mode or Active mode, but still no success.

Any good suggestions will be welcomed.

[image: FTP Connection settings]

Comment: Disable Passive mode and check it again. based on FTP server configuration, maybe yours not support it!

Comment: I have tried that option too, it still brings the FTP response 421.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Worked in FilleZilla, but not in phpStorm.

To make it work, in the settings of my provider, I added my country to the whitelist.

[image: To make it work, in the settings of my provider, I added my country to the whitelist]

Answer (score -1):

I finally got it working, the issues must have been from my hosting provider, talked to them and they changed the server where my website was stored. I still dont know exactly what led to such a 421 response, because other projects worked fine with my IDE except for this specific one, which would work with FileZilla but refuse to work with PhpStorm, until my hosting provider made these changes....this one fixed my problem. I hope it gives a hint to someone else out there

Comment: 421 often means "too many connections". E.g. you may have it opened somewhere already ... If it resolved, then all good. if it will repeat -- you would need to provide detailed logs to JetBrains devs and describe your setup in details.

Answer (score -1):

Try using FTPS instead of FTP. use explicit over TLS and enable Passive mode.
It should be worked now